# Generic method able to perform select on every entity of the domain code

Tags: java, hibernate, generics

I would like to have a generic method performing a `SELECT * FROM entity<T> WHERE entity<T>.primaryKey = method_parameter` that I can use on every entity of my domain code.

So far I have this nongeneric method. It returns a list which will always only have one element because the primary keys are unqiue:

```
public static List<App> selectOneApp(int appid) {
    Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getFactory().openSession();
    List<App> list = null;
    Transaction tx = null;

    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();

        CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<App> criteria = builder.createQuery(App.class);
        Root<App> root = criteria.from(App.class);
        criteria.select(root);

        criteria.where(builder.equal(root.get(App_.appId), appid));
        //equivalent to WHERE App.appid = appid

        list = session.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();

        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx != null)
            tx.rollback();
        log.error(e);
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return list;
}
```

I would like it to be somehow like this:

```
public static <T> List<T> selectOneRow(int key, Class<T> clazz) {
    Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getFactory().openSession();
    List<T> list = null;
    Transaction tx = null;

    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();

        CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<T> criteria = builder.createQuery(clazz);
        Root<T> root = criteria.from(clazz);
        criteria.select(root);

        criteria.where(builder.equal(root.get(clazz_.Id), key)); 
        // I got stuck here. How can I pass a generic key?

        list = session.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();

        tx.commit();
        ...
    return list;
}
```

I use hibernate's code generator to generate the domain code automatically. From that I genererate the JPA metamodel and everything is nice and typesafe.

I was thinking I would have to generate some kind of inheritence structure where the parent class only has a get() method and a primary key. All the entity classes that want to use this generic select method then inherit from that parent class. But I am not sure how to do that or if it is even possible.

This question was my reference but it is missing the criteria.where part: [Java class - how to pass Generic Object to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29900006/java-class-how-to-pass-generic-object-to-a-function)

Snippet from my data model:

```
CREATE TABLE app_type(
    appTypeID TINYINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    app_type_name VARCHAR(32)
);

CREATE TABLE app(
    appID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    app_name VARCHAR(191),
    appTypeID TINYINT UNSIGNED,
    pubID INT UNSIGNED,
    CONSTRAINT fk_app_appType_appTypeID
        FOREIGN KEY (appTypeID) 
        REFERENCES app_type(appTypeID) 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE);

CREATE TABLE publisher(
    pubID INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    publisher_name VARCHAR(191));

CREATE TABLE ref_app_publisher(
    appID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    pubID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(appID, pubID),
    UNIQUE INDEX ux_refAppPublisher_pubID_appID (pubID, appID),
    CONSTRAINT fk_refAppPublisher_app_appID
        FOREIGN KEY (appID) 
        REFERENCES app(appID) 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_refAppPublisher_publisher_pubID 
        FOREIGN KEY (pubID) 
        REFERENCES publisher(pubID)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

Thanks!

Comment: hibernate Session : <T> T get(Class<T> entityType, Serializable id) method do not work for you ?

Comment: @Thierry Thanks,  `Session : <T> T get(Class<T> entityType, Serializable id)` did not help me in the end but through your comment I digged through the API a little more and found my solution. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I succeeded!

The caller will always know what class or entity the operation is supposed to work on. So the trick was to give the caller more responsibility by adding ther parameters `ormClass` and `singularAttribute`.

```
/**
 * Select a single row from any ORM type. Returns a single result in a list
 * or an empty list. Avoids NoResultException() from JPA's getSingleResult()
 * method
 * 
 * @param key
 *            The unique primary key to select.
 * @param ormClass
 *            The ORM class to select.
 * @param singularAttribute
 *            A JPA SingularAttribute<<ormType>, <primaryKey> data
 *            type> containing the mapping to the primary key.
 * @return list The selected ORM type in a list. If no result the list is
 *         empty.
 */
public static <T, X> List<T> selectOneRow(int key, Class<T> ormClass,
        SingularAttribute<T, X> singularAttribute) {
    Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getFactory().openSession();
    List<T> list = null;
    Transaction tx = null;

    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();

        CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<T> criteria = builder.createQuery(ormClass);
        Root<T> root = criteria.from(ormClass);
        criteria.select(root);
        criteria.where(builder.equal(root.get(singularAttribute), key));

        list = session.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();

        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx != null)
            tx.rollback();
        log.error(e);
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return list;
}
```

Note: I encountered an unexplainable NullPointerException when passing SingularAttribute as a parameter that took me a little to figure out. Here is the solution: [Hibernate/JPA - NullPointerException when accessing SingularAttribute parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34823602/hibernate-jpa-nullpointerexception-when-accessing-singularattribute-parameter)